# QGIS plugin start the console

Tags: plugins, qgis, building

Currently I'm building a plugin in QGIS. After starting my plugin I also want the python console automatically started. Is there any way to do that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have stored a reference to QgisInterface (iface) in your plugin, you can use QgisInterface::actionShowPythonDialog():

```py
iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
```